# When I try to insert multiple data into child table then error occurs Could not execute JDBC batch update

Tags: java, jquery, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

I have created two class parent class is Credit and child class is Debit. In Credit class six field is available and in Debit entity only two field is there which is add dynamically - Amount and Description one to many relation with hibernate.

When I try to insert data into two table then this error occurs:

> Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into debit (amount, description, did) values (?, ?, ?)]; constraint [cid]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

```
package com.rojmat.controller;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.apache.commons.collections.bag.SynchronizedSortedBag;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import com.rojmat.entity.Credit;
import com.rojmat.entity.Debit;
import com.rojmat.entity.User;
import com.rojmat.service.CreditService;
import com.rojmat.service.UserService;
import com.rojmat.validation.UserValidation;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    CreditService creditService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(ModelMap model)
    {
        model.put("userData", new User());
        return "/";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveForm(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("userData")@Valid User user,BindingResult br,HttpSession session)
    {   
        UserValidation userValidation = new UserValidation();
        userValidation.validate(userValidation, br);    
        if(br.hasErrors()) {
            return "/";
        }else {
            userService.add(user);
            //session.setAttribute("user", user);
            return "redirect:/";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doLogin(ModelMap model,@ModelAttribute(value="userData")User user,HttpSession session)
    {   
        if(userService.loginUser(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword()) != null)  {
            session.setAttribute("email",user.getEmail());
            return "redirect:useraccount";
        }else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Email/Password");
            model.put("failed", "Invalid Email/Password");
            return "redirect:/";
        }   
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/logout",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logOut(ModelMap model, HttpSession session)
    {
        session.removeAttribute("email");
        return "/";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/useraccount",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showUserAccount(@ModelAttribute("command")Credit credit, BindingResult br)
    {
        return "useraccount";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/useraccount", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String userAccount(@ModelAttribute("command")Credit credit, Debit debit, BindingResult br, HttpSession session)
    {
        try {
            //session.setAttribute("useraccount", credit);
            //session.setAttribute("useraccount", debit);
            System.out.println("Amount= "+debit.getAmount());
            System.out.println("Description= "+debit.getDescription());
            creditService.addCreditDebit(credit);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "redirect:useraccount";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/invoicehome", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String invoiceHome(@ModelAttribute("command")User user, BindingResult br) {
        return "invoice";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/productshome", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String productsHome(@ModelAttribute("command")User user, BindingResult br) {
        return "products";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/paymenthome", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String paymentHome(@ModelAttribute("command")User user, BindingResult br) {
        return "payment";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/userprofilehome", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userProfileHome(@ModelAttribute("command")User user, BindingResult br) {
        return "userprofile";
    }
}
```

```
package com.rojmat.entity;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

@Entity
@Table(name="credit")
public class Credit extends BaseEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private long cid;
    @Column @Order
    private long openingbalance;
    @Column
    private Date date;
    @Column @Order
    private long debittotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long drawertotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long todaybusiness;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="cid")
    @IndexColumn(name="idx")
    private List<Debit> debit;
    public Credit() {

    }
    public Credit(long cid, long openingbalance, Date date, long debittotal, long drawertotal,
            long debittotalplusdrawertotal, long todaybusiness, List<Debit> debit) {
        super();
        this.cid = cid;
        this.openingbalance = openingbalance;
        this.date = date;
        this.debittotal = debittotal;
        this.drawertotal = drawertotal;
        this.debittotalplusdrawertotal = debittotalplusdrawertotal;
        this.todaybusiness = todaybusiness;
        this.debit = debit;
    }
    public long getCid() {
        return cid;
    }
    public void setCid(long cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }
    public long getOpeningbalance() {
        return openingbalance;
    }
    public void setOpeningbalance(long openingbalance) {
        this.openingbalance = openingbalance;
    }   
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public long getDebittotal() {
        return debittotal;
    }
    public void setDebittotal(long debittotal) {
        this.debittotal = debittotal;
    }
    public long getDrawertotal() {
        return drawertotal;
    }
    public void setDrawertotal(long drawertotal) {
        this.drawertotal = drawertotal;
    }
    public long getDebittotalplusdrawertotal() {
        return debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    }
    public void setDebittotalplusdrawertotal(long debittotalplusdrawertotal) {
        this.debittotalplusdrawertotal = debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    }
    public long getTodaybusiness() {
        return todaybusiness;
    }
    public void setTodaybusiness(long todaybusiness) {
        this.todaybusiness = todaybusiness;
    }
    public List<Debit> getDebit() { 
        return debit;
    }   
    public void setDebit(List<Debit> debit) {   
        this.debit = debit;
    }   
}
```

```
package com.rojmat.entity;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(name="debit")
public class Debit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private long did;
    @Column
    private long amount;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cid", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
    private Credit credit;
    @Column
    private String description; 

    public Debit() {

    }
    public Debit(long amount, String description) {
        super();
        this.amount = amount;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public long getDid() {
        return did;
    }
    public void setDid(long did) {
        this.did = did;
    }
    public long getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(long amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public Credit getCredit() {
        return credit;
    }
    public void setCredit(Credit credit) {
        this.credit = credit;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

```
package com.rojmat.serviceImpl;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.rojmat.dao.CreditDao;
import com.rojmat.entity.Credit;
import com.rojmat.entity.Debit;
import com.rojmat.entity.User;
import com.rojmat.service.CreditService;

@Service
@Transactional
public class CreditServiceImpl implements CreditService {

    @Autowired
    private CreditDao creditDao;
    @Override
    public void addCreditDebit(Credit credit) {
        Debit debit = new Debit();
        User user = new User();
     // Credit Data Set
        credit.setOpeningbalance(credit.getOpeningbalance());
        credit.setDate(credit.getDate());
        credit.setDebittotal(credit.getDebittotal());
        credit.setDrawertotal(credit.getDrawertotal());
        credit.setDebittotalplusdrawertotal(credit.getDebittotalplusdrawertotal());
        credit.setTodaybusiness(credit.getTodaybusiness());
        credit.setCreatedBy(user.getEmail());
        credit.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        credit.setUpdatedBy(user.getEmail());
        credit.setUpdatedDate(new Date());
    //  Debit Data set  
        List<Debit> debList = new ArrayList<Debit>();
        credit.setDebit(debList);
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            debList.add(new Debit(debit.getAmount(), debit.getDescription()));
        }
        credit.getDebit().addAll(debList);
        System.out.println("Debit List= "+debList);
        credit.setDebit(debList);
        creditDao.addCreditDebit(credit);
    }
    @Override
    public void updateCreditDebit(Credit credit) {
        Credit creditdebit = new Credit();
        User user = new User();
        creditdebit.setDebit(credit.getDebit());
        creditdebit.setOpeningbalance(credit.getOpeningbalance());
        creditdebit.setDate(credit.getDate());
        creditdebit.setDebittotal(credit.getDebittotal());
        creditdebit.setDrawertotal(credit.getDrawertotal());
        creditdebit.setDebittotalplusdrawertotal(credit.getDebittotalplusdrawertotal());
        creditdebit.setTodaybusiness(credit.getTodaybusiness());
        creditdebit.setCreatedBy(user.getEmail());
        creditdebit.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        creditdebit.setUpdatedBy(user.getEmail());
        creditdebit.setUpdatedDate(new Date());
        creditDao.updateCreditDebit(creditdebit);
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteCreditDebit(int cid) {
        creditDao.deleteCreditDebit(cid);
    }
    @Override
    public List<Credit> getAllCreditDebit() {
        return creditDao.getAllCreditDebit();
    }

}
```

```
package com.rojmat.daoImpl;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.rojmat.dao.CreditDao;
import com.rojmat.entity.Credit;

@Repository
public class CreditDaoImpl implements CreditDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Override
    public void addCreditDebit(Credit credit) {

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(credit);
        /*Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try
        {
            session.save(credit);
            tx.commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            session.close();
            tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

    }

    @Override
    public void updateCreditDebit(Credit credit) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try
        {
            session.update(credit);
            tx.commit();
            session.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            session.close();
            tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteCreditDebit(int cid) {
        /*Credit credit = (Credit)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Credit as c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.debit where c.cid="+cid).uniqueResult();
        List<Debit> debits = credit.getDebit();
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(credit);
        debits.forEach((debit) -> {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(debit);
        });*/


    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Credit> getAllCreditDebit() {
        List<Credit> credits = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Credit,Debit").list();
        return credits;
    }

}
```

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Accounting</title>   
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/dashboard.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.5/validator.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<!-- Navigation Bar -->     
<section id="nav-bar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="" src=""></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/useraccount">Rojmat</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link">Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/category/addCategory">Category</a></li>
                <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/product/addProduct">Product</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/unit/addUnit">Unit</a></li>
                <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/gst/addGst">GST</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link">Payment <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/paymentt/paytype">Payment Mode</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sales/addsales">Sales Payment</a></li>
                <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/purchase/addpurchasepay">Purchase Payment</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link">Ledger<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/cust/addcustomer">Customer</a></li>
                <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/supp/addsupplier">Supplier</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/state/addstate">States</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/invoicehome">Invoice</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/userprofilehome">User Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">LogOut</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</section>      
    <h1>Rojmat (Daily Account)</h1><br/>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/useraccount" method="POST" id="myForm" modelAttribute="command">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <h3>Credit Account</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <form:label path="openingbalance">Opening Balance :</form:label>
                    <form:input path="openingbalance" id="openingBalance" value="${user.openingbalance}" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Opening Balance"/>
                    <small id="openingBalancechk"></small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <form:label path="debittotalplusdrawertotal">Debit Total + Drawer Total :</form:label>
                    <form:input path="debittotalplusdrawertotal" id="debitplusdrawertotal" value="${user.debitplusdrawertotal}" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"/>
                    <small id="debitplusdrawertotalchk"></small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <form:label path="todaybusiness">Today Business :</form:label>
                    <form:input path="todaybusiness" id="todaybusiness" value="${user.todaybusiness}" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"/>
                    <small id="todaybusinesschk"></small>
                </div>
                <%-- <div class="form-group">
                    <form:label path="date">Date :</form:label>
                    <form:input path="date" id="date" value="${user.date}" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"/>
                    <small id="datechk"></small>
                </div> --%>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="savebtn">Save</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Debit Account</h3>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Row" id="addRow"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteRow" value="Delete"/><br>
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tableid">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Select</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody> 
                </table>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <form:label path="debittotal">Debit Total:</form:label>
                    <form:input path="debittotal" id="debittotal" value="${user.debittotal}" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"/>
                    <small id="debittotalchk"></small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <form:label path="drawertotal">Drawer Total :</form:label>
                    <form:input path="drawertotal" id="drawertotal" value="${user.drawertotal}" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"/>
                    <small id="drawertotalchk"></small>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form:form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/dashboard.js"/>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#addRow").click(function(){
                var dc='amount' + parseInt($('[data-val="amount"]').length +1);
                var dcAmount= parseInt($('[data-val="amount"]').length +1);
                var dc1='amountchk' + parseInt($('[data-val="amount"]').length +1);
                var markup = "<c:forEach items='${Debit.debit}' var='debit' varStatus='status'>" + "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td>"+
                        "<td><input type='text' name='amount' id='amount' class='form-control'/>" + "<small id='amountchk' class="+dc1+"></small></td>" +
                        "<td><input type='text' name='description' id='description' class='form-control'/></td></tr>"+"</c:forEach>";
                $("table tbody").append(markup);
            });
            $("#addRow").click(function() {
                $('input[name="amount"]').css({
                    "font-size": "13px",
                    "color": "#777",
                    "border-radius": "20px",
                    "border": "none !important"
                });

                $('input[name="description"]').css({
                    "font-size": "13px",
                    "color": "#777",
                    "border-radius": "20px",
                    "border": "none !important"
                });
            });
            // remove selected table rows
            $("#deleteRow").click(function(){
                $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
                    if($(this).is(":checked")){
                        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                    }
                });
            });
            /*******Debit Total *****************/
            $("#tableid").on('input','#amount',function(){
                var total = 0;
                $("#tableid #amount").each(function() {
                    var get_value = $(this).val();
                    if($.isNumeric(get_value)) {
                        total += parseInt(get_value); 
                    }
                });
                $("#debittotal").val(total);
            });

            /*******Debit Total + Drawer Total *****************/
            $('#debittotal').keyup(function() {
                debitPlusDrawer();
            });
            $('#drawertotal').keyup(function() {
                debitPlusDrawer();
            });
            function debitPlusDrawer() {
                var debit_total = $('#debittotal').val();
                var drawer_total = $('#drawertotal').val();
                var debit_Drawer = parseInt(debit_total) + parseInt(drawer_total);
                if($.isNumeric(debit_Drawer)) {
                    $("#debitplusdrawertotal").val(debit_Drawer);
                }
            }

            /*************** DebitTotalPlus_DrawerTotal - Opening_Balance **********/

            $('#debitplusdrawertotal').keyup(function() {
                Debit_minus_OpeningBalace();
            });$('#openingBalance').keyup(function() {
                Debit_minus_OpeningBalace();
            });

            function Debit_minus_OpeningBalace() {
                var debit_Drawer = $('#debitplusdrawertotal').val();
                var opening_Balance = $('#openingBalance').val();
                var today_Business = parseInt(debit_Drawer) - parseInt(opening_Balance);
                if($.isNumeric(today_Business)) {
                    $("#todaybusiness").val(today_Business);
                }
            }

            $('#openingBalancechk').hide();
            $('#debittotalchk').hide();
            $('#drawertotalchk').hide();
            $('#debitplusdrawertotalchk').hide();
            $('#todaybusinesschk').hide();
           // $('#datechk').hide();
            $('#amountchk').hide();

            var openingBalance_err = true;
            var debittotal_err = true;
            var drawertotal_err = true;
            var debitdrawertotal_err = true;
            var todaybusiness_err = true;
        //    var date_err = true;
            var amount_err = true;

            $('#openingBalance').keyup(function() {
                openingBalance_chk();
            });
            function openingBalance_chk() {
                var openingbalance = $('#openingBalance').val();
                var pattern = /^\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/;
                if((openingbalance.length == '') || (openingbalance.length == null)) {
                    $('#openingBalancechk').show();
                    $('#openingBalancechk').html("Please Fill Opening Balance");
                    $('#openingBalancechk').focus();
                    $('#openingBalancechk').css("color","red");
                    openingBalance_err = false;
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $('#openingBalancechk').hide();
                }
                if(!pattern.test(openingbalance)) {
                    $('#openingBalancechk').show();
                    $('#openingBalancechk').html("Please enter only numbers 0-9");
                    $('#openingBalancechk').focus();
                    $('#openingBalancechk').css("color","red");
                    openingBalance_err = false;
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $('#openingBalancechk').hide();
                }
            }

            $('#debittotal').keyup(function() {
                debittotal_chk();
            });

            function debittotal_chk() {
                var debittotal = $('#debittotal').val();
                var pattern = /^\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/;
                if((debittotal.length == '') || (debittotal.length == null)) {
                    $('#debittotalchk').show();
                    $('#debittotalchk').html("Please Fill Debit Total");
                    $('#debittotalchk').focus();
                    $('#debittotalchk').css("color","red");
                    debittotal_err = false;
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $('#debittotalchk').hide();
                }
                if(!pattern.test(debittotal)) {
                    $('#debittotalchk').show();
                    $('#debittotalchk').html("Please enter only numbers 0-9");
                    $('#debittotalchk').focus();
                    $('#debittotalchk').css("color","red");
                    debittotal_err = false;
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $('#debittotalchk').hide();
                }
            }


        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class Debit

In your class `CreditServiceImpl` in function `addCreditDebit` you do :

```
credit.setDebit(debList);
creditDao.addCreditDebit(credit);
```

so you set the attribute `debit` and then you update or update your entity credit.

But in your class `Debit` there is the line :

```
@JoinColumn(name="cid", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
private Credit credit;
```

Try to remove `insertable=false` and `updatable=false`

Comment: I will get normal data when i call this method debit.getAmount() - 10,20,30 and debit.getDescription() - aa, bb, cc this is normal data that data is not set into CreditServiceImpl class because credit.setDebit(this is accept only list of data ) but as per ablove method call that is normal data so hoe to convert that simple data into list and how to pass that list con you help me ?